# How to get Autofill address searchbar in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

[image]

How do I implement this in my iPhone project using UISearchebar controller. Is there any tutorial for this in iPHone/xcode. I have heard about google api for the same but I didnt get anything for the same. Can anyone provide me simple tutorial/link for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these two links, you will surely get what you are looking for.

1. http://ygamretuta.me/2011/09/14/implement-autocomplete-ios-search-display-controller/
2. http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/doautocompletetextfield

Comment: In above links they have manually string arrays. But in my case I am doing map application for Australia continent. So how can I put so many address location of Australia in just array string. If I do then ....will the Apple accept my project code in appstore???

Comment: @NavnathMemane You can create a WebService and then call that webService when your app starts. and save the response to a NSarray. If in future there is any change you just have to update your WebService and you are ready to call it again.

Comment: @NavnathMemane Apple will not be going through your code. They will only see that wether you follow the HIG(human interface guide) or not.

Comment: @NavnathMemane One more solution is to save all your data in a plist file and add that file to your project and use it when it requires..as simple as that..:D

Comment: Hello Ajeet I have successfully tried your method. But my client would like to use google web service for autocomplete address. I have read this http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html. Do you know how to call google link serevice. Do you have any idea. In android it has very simple and small code. I want this for iPhone

Comment: I have gone through google documentation they have given that the submitted query will be a url with your keyword to be searched and the output can be in Json or in xml. so what you can do is just create a  webservice(either using json or XMLRPC) then you can easily parse the output and show it on your app.

Comment: Ok so it is like web service using NSURL method for calling google url and then I have to create class for parsing the data. Or is there any tutorial on this to follow...

Comment: Hi Ajeet my client has sent me the data of australian postal code..which is list of 16,456. I am just taking in array list again like before and it is working fine too. I have not used google webserise. Is this ok with Apple policy???